# Is "relax a little" negated?

Tags: meaning, negation

I'd like to know what this structure really means. It's confusing. But anyway, I'm inclined to meaning 2.

S: We should not let our work take over our lives and relax a little.

Meaning 1: We should not let our work take over our lives and **should** relax a little.

Meaning 2: We should not let our work take over our lives and **should not** relax a little.

Answer (score 1):

It should be meaning 1, as "should not let our work take over our lives" means that you should not work too much, which means that you "*should* relax a little".

Answer (score 0):

It's a badly written sentence. The intended meaning is obviously (1), as DialFrost says, but the grammatical meaning is (2). As the main verb is negative, the implied verb for *relax* should also be understood as negative.

It would be better expressed as *We should not let our work take over our lives; we should relax a little.*

Comment: The grammatical meaning is 2, as Kate said. Specifically, "We should not let our work take over our lives and not relax a little." If our work takes over, we will not relax even a little. Kate's reword is clearer.